# redmine - web service authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, authentication, redmine

I am working on Rails 2.3.5. In my redmine app I am providing web services for iphone.
How to authenticate a user from iphone and after login how my rails app identify me as a logged user. Whether i need to provide any token after login and using token for further request for an API call. please suggest me the way to implement authentication for an iphone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in-depth documentation for rest API provided on the redmine [wiki](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Authentication) itself. Even a redmine app already exists for Iphone